# How to have beforeunload functionality with hashchange?

Tags: javascript, html

This code here works for a page refresh or closing the page. It pops up a dialog asking if you're sure you want to leave without saving.

```
 $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
      return 'Did you save your changes?';
 });
```

Trouble is I have a SPA and I'd like this to show on hashchange as well.
The alert works here but returning a string does nothing. I'm guessing that that dialog is 
specific to the beforeunload event.

```
 $(window).on('hashchange', function(){
     alert("saved?");
     return "this doesn't do anything";
 });
```

How should I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have to capture click event on the hashes and cancel it if not confirmed:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    return confirm('Did you save your changes?')
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v8GbN/**

Comment: What if the user uses back or forward buttons?